# How to make an ListView.builder or List index static in Dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, arraylist, shopping-cart

I am building a flutter app that increment a index value on a list as a result of a user's interaction.

```
class _CheckoutScreenState extends State<CheckoutScreen>{
List<int> quantity = [1, 2, 1, 6];
void increment(int index){
 setState((){
   quantity[index] +=1;
 });
}
void decrement(int index){
  if(quantity[index] != 0){
  setState((){
   quantity[index] -=1;
 });
}
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
 return ListView.builder(
 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
  return quantity[index] != 0 ? 
   ListTile(
    leading: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
    onPressed: (){
     decrement(index);
    }
   ),
   trailing: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: (){
     increment(index);
    }
   ),
   title: Text('${quantity[index].toString()} products')
  )
 }
 )
}
}
```

When I run this code, and then remove an item (once an item is 0, it is not displayed on the screen), the index is shifted as ListView.Builder rebuilds.
For example, if I removed the item (making its quantity 0) at index 2, the index should look like

```
  [1,2,0,6]
```

but as a result of the list view builder, the index shifts, and the listview builder only has

```
  [1,2,6]
```

which is discontinous from the main list. How do I make this index static in listView builder so it won't be shifted whenever it needs to be rebuilt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace List with a Map and display the current index quantity as a Map, that way each map key represents a unique identifier